# Ordered Lists Html Page Tabs to Open Webpages in same page

Tags: html, css

So I'm building a site and I want to have little tabs on the right hand side that will change the content on the main page without having to refresh the entire page, like an embedded page within the main page. I am working from a template (HTML and CS) and trying to modify the existing content. In the code you can notice that there is an ordered list which defines the buttons (Like Homepage and etc) and when hovered over they change background and look fancy, but they don't actually do anything. I've been reading up about how to make them change the page (by following a link) but I am confused and can't figure out how to do it. I was hoping you guys could help me. I'm very noobish to HTML and CSS and just trying to put something together and learn from example while also building a private site. Thank you for your help in advance!

**INDEX.HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>/rootbox</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div id="header" class="container">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1><a href="#">Rootbox</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Distros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Wifi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="banner">
            <div class="content"><img src="images/title.png" width="1000" height="300" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #header -->

    <div id="page">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="post">
                <h2 class="title"><a href="#">Welcome to /rootbox</a></h2>
                <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="entry">
                    <p>/rootbox is a collection of Security oriented Tools, Tutorials, Resources and Websites.This site offers a collection of well documented and freely available tools and resources for both a begginer pen-tester and the professional white-hat. Everything on this site is simply a collection, thus no original content is posted. All links have been tested and properly checked for security. All software published here is free and available directly from the author's site. Tutorials are often updated and deprecated software is removed.
                    </br></br>
                    This site is hosted on Panckake.io - A web framework which allows for publishing websites directly from Dropbox. For more information go <a href="http://pancake.io">here</a>.If you need any additional help, or have any feedback or suggestions, send an email to rushone2010@gmail.com.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <!-- end #content -->
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>Copyright (c) 2012. All rights reserved. Design by <a href="http://www.freecsstemplates.org">FCT</a></p>
</div>
<!-- end #footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

**STYLE.CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #050505 url(images/img01.jpg) repeat;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5B5B5B;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #222222;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2.8em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}

p, ul, ol {
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 180%;
}

ul, ol {
}

a {
    color: #5E5E5E;
}

a:hover {
}

#wrapper {
    background: #FFFFFF url(images/img05.jpg) repeat;
}

.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

/* Header */

#header-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}

/* Logo */

#logo {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#logo h1, #logo p {
}

#logo h1 {
    line-height: 120px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    font-size: 3.8em;
}

#logo h1 a {
    color: #1F1F1F;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

#logo p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0 0 0px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font: normal 18px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #8E8E8E;
}

#logo p a {
    color: #8E8E8E;
}

#logo a {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

/* Splash */

#splash {
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

/* Search */

#search {
    float: right;
    width: 280px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#search form {
    height: 41px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 20px;
}

#search fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

#search-text {
    width: 170px;
    padding: 6px 5px 2px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #E7EBED;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font: normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #5D781D;
}

#search-submit {
    width: 50px;
    height: 22px;
    border: none;
    background: #B9B9B9;
    color: #000000;
}

/* Menu */

#menu {
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}

#menu li {
    float: right;
}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #1F1F1F;
    border: none;
}

#menu a:hover, #menu .current_page_item a {
    background: url(images/img01.jpg) repeat;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu .current_page_item a {
}

/* Page */

#page {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 0px;
}

/* Content */

#content {


    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.post {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E7EBED;
}

.post .title {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.post .title a {
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #222222;
}

.post .meta {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.post .meta .date {
    float: left;
}

.post .meta .posted {
    float: right;
}

.post .meta a {
}

.post .entry {
    padding: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.links {
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.more {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 88px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #222222;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.comments {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 88px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    background: #222222;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Sidebar */

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#sidebar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#sidebar li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#sidebar li ul {
    margin: 0px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#sidebar li li {
    line-height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E7EBED;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    border-left: none;
}

#sidebar li li span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: italic;
}

#sidebar li li a {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    background: url(images/img04.jpg) no-repeat left 50%;
}

#sidebar h2 {
    height: 38px;
    padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
    letter-spacing: -.5px;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #222222;
}

#sidebar p {
    margin: 0 0px;
    padding: 0px 30px 20px 30px;
    text-align: justify;
}

#sidebar a {
    border: none;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Calendar */

#calendar {
}

#calendar_wrap {
    padding: 20px;
}

#calendar table {
    width: 100%;
}

#calendar tbody td {
    text-align: center;
}

#calendar #next {
    text-align: right;
}

/* Three Column Footer Content */

#footer-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    color: #D6E2F0;
}

#footer-content a {
    color: #92A9B6;
}

#footer-bg {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    background: #E8E8E8;
}

#footer-content h2 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #262626;
}


#footer-content #fbox1 {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#footer-content #fbox2 {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

#footer-content #fbox3 {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}

#footer-content a {
}

#column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 290px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

#column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
}

#column3 {
    float: right;
    width: 260px;
}

/* Footer */

#footer {
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 0 15px 0;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
}

#footer p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #5E5E5E;
}

#footer a {
    color: #5E5E5E;
}

#marketing {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #E7EBED;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E7EBED;
}

#marketing .text1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #345E9B;
}

#marketing .text2 {
    float: right;
}

#marketing .text2 a {
    display: block;
    width: 252px;
    height: 38px;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: url(images/img07.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#banner {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 340px;
    background: url(images/img03.png) no-repeat left bottom;
}

#banner .content {
}


.list-style1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.list-style1 a {
    color: #7F7F7F;
}
```

Comment: are you asking how to make a page redirect when a user hovers over a link?

Comment: No actually I want to be bale to click on one of the tabs and the rest of the page will be redirected to another page. Let me just show you visually: 
This is the Home Page: http://i.imgur.com/Lv1T7.png
And when I click on, lets say, the distros button you get this:http://i.imgur.com/Qzekt.png

Comment: I understand what you mean. Make a jsfiddle at jsfiddle.net and include the elements in question, then i can help you work out your issues in a collaborative forum. Try to minimize the code displayed so that it is easier to read, and your future questions will most likely yield better results.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#menu #tab1').on('mouseover', function () {
                    $('#page').show();
                    $('#page2,#page3,#page4,#page5').hide();    
                }); 
                $('#menu #tab2').on('mouseover', function () {
                    $('#page2').show();
                    $('#page,#page3,#page4,#page5').hide(); 
                });
                $('#menu #tab3').on('mouseover', function () {
                    $('#page3').show();
                    $('#page,#page2,#page4,#page5').hide(); 
                });
                $('#menu #tab4').on('mouseover', function () {
                    $('#page4').show();
                    $('#page,#page2,#page3,#page5').hide(); 
                });
                $('#menu #tab5').on('mouseover', function () {
                    $('#page5').show();
                    $('#page,#page2,#page3,#page4').hide(); 
                });

    });
</script>
```

Try this on your script and html..

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div id="header" class="container">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1><a href="#">Rootbox</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="current_page_item" id="tab1"><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
                    <li id="tab2"><a href="#">Distros</a></li>
                    <li id="tab3"><a href="#">Wifi</a></li>
                    <li id="tab4"><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
                    <li id="tab5"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="banner">
            <div class="content"><img src="images/title.png" width="1000" height="300" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #header -->

    <div id="page">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="post">
                <h2 class="title"><a href="#">Welcome to /rootbox</a></h2>
                <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="entry">
                    <p>/rootbox is a collection of Security oriented Tools, Tutorials, Resources and Websites.This site offers a collection of well documented and freely available tools and resources for both a begginer pen-tester and the professional white-hat. Everything on this site is simply a collection, thus no original content is posted. All links have been tested and properly checked for security. All software published here is free and available directly from the author's site. Tutorials are often updated and deprecated software is removed.
                    </br></br>
                    This site is hosted on Panckake.io - A web framework which allows for publishing websites directly from Dropbox. For more information go <a href="http://pancake.io">here</a>.If you need any additional help, or have any feedback or suggestions, send an email to rushone2010@gmail.com.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page2">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="post">
                <h2 class="title"><a href="#">page2</a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div id="page3">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="post">
                <h2 class="title"><a href="#">page3</a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page4">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="post">
                <h2 class="title"><a href="#">page4</a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page5">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="post">
                <h2 class="title"><a href="#">page5</a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add this to your style..

```
#page2, #page3, #page4, #page5{
display:none;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 0px;
}
```

note:change the #content to class type..

Comment: `note:change the #content to class type..`

What do you mean?

Comment: Because I used the #content many times so I change it to .content to make it global. :)

Comment: Oh ok, well I've tried but nothing seems to happen. Am I doing something wrong. I've added the the script to the beginning of the HTML page and replaced the HTML part with yours. I've also added the CSS snip, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are looking for a way to load content on mouseover, here is what I would suggest:

Use a little bit o' jQuery and AJAX:

```
$("#menu a").on("mouseover",function(){
//Get url of link
var url = $(this).attr('href');
//Perform ajax call to said link
$.ajax(
    {
    url:"/echo/json",
    success:function(data){
        //USED FOR MOCKING PURPOSES ONLY
       data = exampleContent; 

        //Append the data to your content wrapper
        $("#page #content").html(data[url]);
    }
});
});
```

**[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/5EZNy/)**

**[This is a fancier version with fading.  I call that a splash of awesome](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/Dk8GP/1/)**

Comment: Wow this is cool but I would rather not get into something as complex as AJAX right away. I'm just a beginner and trying to set something up so that it works. Thank you for your great suggestion though I think it works great and looks great.

Comment: @litebread Thank you for your kind words.  Then just pre-loading the content, hiding initial hiders, adding '#DIVID' to your link's href, and then showing/hiding based on that would work great as well.  

I am just an AJAX kind of guy at heart I guess :).

Comment: Hehe no problem I try to be nice because I am receiving help from people who are often under appreciated. Regarding your directions, I will have to look all that up. I'm that much of a noob. I'll follow your suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

If i were you, i would use css property

```
display: none;
```

on the elements that you are hiding initially, then use jquery's

```
.toggle()
```

method to fade in the elements when the user clicks the link. As in

```
$('.target').toggle();
```

Where target is the name of your div id.

Comment: Honestly man I barely know divs and I am very new to this. This is some intense work that I though would be a lot easier to implement. I guess I need to go study HTML and CSS more and properly learn as to how to do this.